# Removing object from an array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm pushing div component to my array when clicking on a button if some conditions are met. And i'm displaying my list in my view. It works well but i'm facing a problem when trying to remove a div component from my array.Why is my list not updating when i try to remove a object from the array but it's working when i''m adding a object to the array? I want to update my array even when i remove objects from the array so it should remove the div component i'm removing in real time.

I have checked using console logs and the code is working correctly as it removes div component when i click on `removetextpoll` but the problem is my view remains unchaged.

my code is as follows.

```
class TextVotePost extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      addOption: 3,
      maxImage: 4,
      optionBtn: true,
    };
    this.addOption = this.addOption.bind(this);
  }

  addOption() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      addOption: ++prevState.addOption,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    let list = [];
    const textPollMaxLength = 35;

    function removetextpoll() {
      list.splice(0, 1);
    }

    for (let i = 3; i <= this.state.maxImage; i++) {
      {
        this.state.addOption > i &&
          list.push(
            <div key={i}>
              <div className="txt_vote_bar_div">
                <div onClick={removetextpoll} />

                <Field
                  name={`inputName${i}`}
                  component="input"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder={`Option ${i}`}
                  maxLength={textPollMaxLength}
                />
              </div>
            </div>,
          );
      }
    }

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
        {list}
        <div onClick={this.addOption}>
          <span>Add Option</span>
        </div>
        }
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A rerender is triggered by a state or prop change.

Comment: while adding, you are setting state that triggers a re-render, however while deleting, you aren't doing any such thing, so while the data may be deleted, its not reflecting in the UI

Answer (score 0):

React components only re-render when their state or props change. The list isn't part of the state or props, it's just some list you declared in your render function.

When you add an option, you're changing the state in `addOption()`, but for removing an option you're just splicing that array directly. You need to do the editing of the list via the state or props in order for the change to trigger a re-render and your view to be updated.

And as someone commented (looks like they removed it now), be aware of the difference between `splice()` and `slice()`. Directly mutating the state/props won't trigger a re-render and will also cause bugs and strange behaviour. To change props you need to pass a new prop, or to change the state you need to use `setState()`.

Comment: so what's the approach i should take to solve this problem?